# Search part in navbar doesn't work properly (django)

Tags: django, search, django-queryset

I wanted to create a search box in my navbar and show the food which I search, but it seems it doesn't work properly. I can't find out where's the problem; I mean if I search a food which exists it shows me nothing.

my views.py file:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Food
    template_name = "restaurant/food_search_results.html"
    context_object_name = "data"

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.POST.get("search")
        if query is not None:
            return Food.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
        else:
            return
```

my urls.py file:

```
path("search", SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
```

my base.html file:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="/search" method="get">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="input-group">
              <label>
                  <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Foods ...">
              </label>
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-warning" href="{% url 'search_results' %}" type="submit" >Search</a>
              </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem   I mean if I search a food which exists it shows me nothing and when I print the query it prints None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You submit the form with a `<button type="submit"></button>`, so you should change the form to:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="input-group">
      <label>
          <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Foods ...">
      </label>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Search</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In the view we then search with:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Food
    template_name = 'restaurant/food_search_results.html'
    context_object_name = 'data'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')  # 🖘 use GET
        if query is not None:
            return Food.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
        else:
            return Food.objects.none()  # 🖘 otherwise still return a queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you search is not returning any queryset is because you are posting the query, instead of getting the querySet. This is acutually where you missed the query = self.request.POST.get("search"), Instend of query = self.request.GET.get("search")

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Food
    template_name = "restaurant/food_search_results.html"
    context_object_name = "data"

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get("search")
        if query is not None:
            return Food.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
        else:
            return Food.objects.none()
```

Comment: I've changed it to GET but when I print the query it prints None.

Comment: Did you make the query in your search box  and are you  sure you have data of food saved in your backend ?

Comment: You might have to look at your search form too!